# How can I align an image with the spectrogram in Praat?

Tags: phonetics, praat

I am looking for a way to create a new image display in praat that is aligned with the waveform and spectrogram. The image display must be an object in the object window. It must be groupable with the spectrogram. When you zoom in or out of one the other stays aligned accordingly. The images are frames of an ultrasound video located every 33 ms. The tongue position in each ultrasound frame will correlate with the spectrogram and waveform. If anyone can help, I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? What do you mean by "create a new image display in Praat"? You mean you want it to be some kind of object in the object window? And you want it to be groupable with the spectrogram such that if you zoom in or out of one the other stays aligned accordingly? And what do you mean by "frames"? Do you mean freeze-frames of video footage?

Comment: user, welcome to Linguistics SE! Please edit your question according to musicallinguist suggestions by clicking "edit" below your question, thank you. :)

Comment: Hi musical linguist and Alenanno. Thank you for the suggestions. I did the changes following from your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I doubt this is possible. Praat doesn't have such an object, as far as I am aware.

If you think about it, if there were such an interface, it probably wouldn't make sense to show all of the images at once, since 33 ms is such a short interval of time (only encompassing a few glottal pulses) and unless the spectrogram and waveform are stretched out quite a bit there won't be room to place a bunch of image frames side-by-side without overlapping. Rather, you'd probably want a tool that displays a single window for a single image that keeps changing depending on where in the spectrogram/waveform you place the cursor (I'm thinking of something analogous to the function in Wavesurfer that allows you to hover over the spectrogram and see a snapshot of the spectrum that corresponds to the relevant point in time).

As I said, though, I'm pretty sure there's nothing in Praat with this kind of functionality. The best alternative I can come up with is to write a script that allows you to select a point on the spectrogram/waveform and then find (in a specified directory) an image file whose name encodes time information that matches the time of the selection. The script would have to open the image file with some other program besides Praat, I think.

Others might have other suggestions. If you're really stuck, you could even contact Paul Boersma directly. His contact info is on [the Praat page](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/).

Comment: musicallinguist, thank you very much for your answer. I will think about the options you mentioned. I really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. Good luck!